# Tabla responsive

Tags: bootstrap, responsive, table

Estoy en un lio desde hace días y no puedo dar con la solución.
Tengo que hacer una tabla de horarios semanales de cursado.. he probado con Bootstrap y no puedo lograr hacerla responsive y que se vea bien. Mi idea es que en móviles muestre de a un solo día con todos los horarios, se me desordena todo cuando pongo la vista mobile.
Tengo este código ahora, he probado otros y tampoco encontré la solución.

```
<div class="container">
            <h2>Horarios</h2>
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md"></div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Lunes</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Martes</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Miércoles</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Jueves</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Viernes</div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md">8:00 - 9:30</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md">10:00 - 11:30</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md">11:35 - 13:00</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-md">13:00 - 14:30</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
                <div class="col-12 col-md">Materia</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: Buen día, ¿Qué versión de Bootstrap estás utilizando?...

Comment: Hola, buenas! la versión 5.3

Comment: Yo pienso que debes seguir la estructura de una tabla (me refiero a usar las etiquetas `table`, `tr` y `td`)... tal cuál como indican en la [documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables) para que sea totalmente responsivo...

Answer (score 0):

Para lograr que tu tabla de horarios sea responsive y se vea bien en dispositivos móviles, puedes seguir algunos ajustes en tu código HTML y hacer uso de las clases de Bootstrap correctamente.

Aquí tienes una versión modificada de tu código para lograrlo:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <h2>Horarios</h2>
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md"></div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Lunes</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Martes</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Miércoles</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Jueves</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Viernes</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md">8:00 - 9:30</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md">10:00 - 11:30</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md">11:35 - 13:00</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 col-md">13:00 - 14:30</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
      <div class="col-12 col-md-2">Materia</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Explicación de los cambios:

Añadí la clase col-12 a la primera columna que estaba vacía. Esto asegura que ocupará todo el ancho disponible en cualquier tamaño de pantalla.

En las demás columnas, cambié col-md por col-md-2 para especificar que ocupen 2 columnas de ancho en dispositivos medianos (md) o mayores. Esto permite que se muestre en una sola fila en pantallas más grandes.

Con estos cambios, la tabla debería verse mejor en dispositivos móviles y mantenerse bien organizada en pantallas más grandes. No olvides también incluir las etiquetas de meta viewport en la sección head de tu página para asegurarte de que la escala de la página sea adecuada en dispositivos móviles:

```html
<head>
  <!-- Otras etiquetas meta y enlaces -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
```

Recuerda que Bootstrap se encarga de hacer que los elementos se adapten automáticamente en diferentes tamaños de pantalla, pero a veces es necesario ajustar las clases para lograr el diseño deseado.

Comment: Hola! como estas, gracias por la respuesta? lo probé pero no me muestra por dia, si ves arriba aparecen todos los dias juntos.